# Convert DBF to CSV using Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to daily load a bunch of tables on Azure SQL DW using Azure Data Factory but I need some help converting DBF tables (to CSV would be nice) prior to loading them up. Can anyone indicate a good way to do this?

Comment: Where is your data stored? If it is in azure blob storage, my suggestion would be to use HDInsight to convert the data and use ADF with PolyBase to import the data.

Comment: Yeah, it's in a blob but how can I convert it using HDInsight?

Comment: You would have to create a custom job in Hadoop and write the results to the blob. Harish's answer is potentially an easier solution that I was unaware of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can leverage the custom activity in ADF to covert the DBF files to CSV first. Here's the pointer on how to leverage the custom activity: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/data-factory-use-custom-activities/ . After the CSV files are created use the copy activity in ADF to copy them to Azure SQL DW.